# Sharepoint2007: Display Document Library Folder contents in customized format?

Tags: document-library, formatting

How can I do a customized view of a Document Library in home page?
I want to show like following:

```
![image][1] **Title of Document** [with link to document]
            Body of articles [Intro Text]
```

Best Regards,
Reds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, as with all things SharePoint. My favorite is with a Data View Web Part (DVWP), which you can create in SharePoint Designer. Because DVWPs are XSL-driven, you have total control over the markup, structure, and look of the output.

Answer (score 2):

When you customize a view, SharePoint allows you to choose among different styles. In your case, you could try a "Summary View", or a "Boxed View".

If none of the out of the box styles suits your needs, then you'll have to use SharePoint Designer for advanced layout customizations. In SharePoint Designer you'll work with a Data View Web Part (SharePoint 2007) or a List View Web Part (SharePoint 2010).

Comment: I want your answer to up vote but my reputation can't :)